# Fonts loading, but I need to use Font.loadAsync

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo

I'm trying to add a custom font to ReactNative using expo
the fonts are actually showing up ok for now, but I keep getting a warning that I should use `Font.loadAsync`, I've tried to adapt what's in the docs to the tabbed template and watched a few tutorials, most recently Maximillian's on Udemy feels the closest.. but even though I'm using Font.loadAsync I'm still getting the same warning.

[Repo, Tabs Template with Custom Fonts](https://github.com/TurtleWolfe/customFont)

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaProvider } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import useCachedResources from './hooks/useCachedResources';
import useColorScheme from './hooks/useColorScheme';
import Navigation from './navigation';

// expo install expo-app-loading
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
// import { AppLoading } from 'expo';

// import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    'CharterBold': require('./assets/fonts/CharterBold.otf'),
    'CharterBoldItalic': require('./assets/fonts/CharterBoldItalic.otf'),
    'CharterItalic': require('./assets/fonts/CharterItalic.otf'),
    'CharterRegular': require('./assets/fonts/CharterRegular.otf'),
    'SpaceMono': require('./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
  })
}

export default function App() {
  const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const [fontsLoaded, setFontsLoaded] = useState(false)

  // const [loaded] = useFonts({
  //   CharterBold: require('./assets/fonts/CharterBold.otf'),
  //   CharterBoldItalic: require('./assets/fonts/CharterBoldItalic.otf'),
  //   CharterItalic: require('./assets/fonts/CharterItalic.otf'),
  //   CharterRegular: require('./assets/fonts/CharterRegular.otf'),
  //   SpaceMono: require('./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
  // });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={fetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => setFontsLoaded(true)}
        onError={(err) => console.log(err)}
      />
    );
  }
  if (!isLoadingComplete) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
        <StatusBar />
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I need under **`./hooks/useCachedResources.ts`**
there is already a section that is using **`await Font.loadAsync`**
I just needed to add my fonts to that section.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder called `hooks` where your `App.js` is located.

Inside that create a file called `useFonts.js`

Your `useFonts.js` should look like this -

```
import * as Font from "expo-font";

const useFonts = async () => {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    CharterBold: require("./assets/fonts/CharterBold.otf"),
    CharterBoldItalic: require("./assets/fonts/CharterBoldItalic.otf"),
    CharterItalic: require("./assets/fonts/CharterItalic.otf"),
    CharterRegular: require("./assets/fonts/CharterRegular.otf"),
    SpaceMono: require("./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf"),
  });
 }

export default useFonts;
```

Now your `App.js` should look like this -

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";

import useCachedResources from "./hooks/useCachedResources";
import useColorScheme from "./hooks/useColorScheme";
import Navigation from "./navigation";

import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import useFonts from "./hooks/useFonts";

export default function App() {
  const isLoadingComplete = useCachedResources();
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  const [IsReady, SetIsReady] = useState(false);

  const FetchFonts = async () => {
    await useFonts();
  };

  if (!IsReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={FetchFonts}
        onFinish={() => SetIsReady(true)}
        onError={(err) => console.log(err)}
      />
    );
  }

  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
      <StatusBar />
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your advice.. unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error I had before.

Comment: Its working perfectly fine. Check [this](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/loading-custom-fonts) out. I've created a Snack and its working perfectly fine.

Comment: I made a snack from my original repo, it suggested a few updates to the package.json, but it's not showing the error either. But when I ran either locally, my original or your suggested updates, I'm still getting the warning. It's loading the fonts, but I figure as the project gets larger it eventually won't and I just feel like it's something I should learn to understand better.
[snack](https://snack.expo.io/@turtlewolfe/0c8776)